# How can I use OpenCV without running 'make install'?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, cmake, compilation

I am new to cmake and OpenCV.

Is there a way that I can use OpenCV on my machine by just building the source code and not installing them to `/usr/local/lib` on my machine, i.e. without running `make install` after building the binaries?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to provide paths to OpenCV libs in your code.

Comment: You'll notice "make" has several targets.  You don't need to execute the "install" target.  I believe there's also a "build" target - that might be sufficient for your purposes.  CAVEAT: "make build" (if I'm guessing the correct target name) will build your CV libraries.  Whatever CV executable you create - you'll need a shell script (or equivalent) for it to find the CVS shared libraries you built.

Comment: You can install anywhere you want by setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution would be to set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to a specific location:

```
# in opencv/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/path/to/deps/
cmake --build . --target install
```

Then, configure your project with the same prefix:

```
# in your project/build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user/path/to/deps/
```

In your cmake files, simply use `find_package(OpenCV)`

Comment: You sir are brilliant!

Comment: This is simply how CMake is meant to be used ;) And this is also how package manager operates: creating a prefix for your app and let `find_package` work.

Comment: understood completely and a much better approach than I had attempted

Comment: Always happy to help!